# Анимация кнопки в Android

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-button

мне нужно на измененную кнопку добавить анимацию как на дефолтной. Нигде ничего подобного не нашел (или просто плохо искал).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь атрибут

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

**UPD**

Если требуется в `background` устанавливать цвет, то можно `Button` заменить на `ImageButton` и `background` использовать для установки цвета, а `src` для установки фона клика.

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:src="?android:selectableItemBackground" />
```

Comment: А если он цветом занят?

Comment: @Arsen можно `Button` на `ImageButton` заменить тогда будут и `src` и `background`. Через `background` можно задать цвет, а через `src`клик. Добавил код

Comment: А если, например, нужен текст?

Comment: Наверное только если поместить в контейнер `LinearLayout` или `FrameLayout` и добавить `TextView`

Comment: Поверх, да? ююю